# Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.myapp.network.QuoteDc> for method c.a

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, retrofit2, moshi

I recently upgraded the Gradle plugin to version: 7.1.2 (My Gradle version is 7.2). After upgrading Retrofit is throwing this exception

> Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.myapp.network.QuoteDc> for method **c.a**

for this data class

```
@Keep
data class QuoteDc (
    @Json(name = "quote") val quote: String
)
```

and this exception

> Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.myapp.network.StatusDc>
> for method **d.a**

for this data class

```
@Keep
data class StatusDc (
    @Json(name = "txt")val txt: String,
    @Json(name = "url") val url: String,
    @Json(name = "updated") val updated: String,
    @Json(name = "token") val token: Int
)
```

*The difference in these two errors is that one ends with "c.a" and the other with "d.a" I don't know what they are.*

But **I was able to fix this error by setting "MinifyEnabled false"**. But surely, I want my application to have a small apk size. So this method is not useful to me.

Somehow, new Gradle Plugin is causing problem with minifyEnabled true. Because, before upgrading Gradle Plugin, all the codes below worked fine with MinifyEnabled true. Please help me to fix this issue.

Here is my Retrofit code for one of the data classes:

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
.build()

private val retrofitQuote = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface QuoteInterface {
    @GET("quotes.json") //end point
    suspend fun getQuote(): List<QuoteDc>
}

object  QuoteApiObj {
    val retrofitQuoteService: QuoteInterface by lazy { retrofitQuote.create(QuoteInterface::class.java) }
}
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.4.2"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

I don't have any proguard-rules.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of moshi-kotlin dependency. Somehow, android studio didn't alert me of the availability of newer version.

I just updated from 1.9.3 to 1.13.0 and it fixed the issue.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0'
```